# How to get the largest size of nested lists with jQuery

Tags: jquery, nested-lists

Here's my issue: I have nested lists, and I want to grab the size of the largest one without grabbing its children, too. For example:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

So it would pull 5 (the main list, or 4 assuming 0 index), instead of of 11 or whatever. Thoughts? I've tried to mess with the size() function, but it grabs the children as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('ul').each(function() {
    console.log($('> li', this).length);
});​
```

Returns 5, 2, 4.

Answer (score 0):

```
var items = $("ul > li");  //looks at all direct children of ul.
var len = items.length; // the length will count the number of occurances of li appear.
```

You can then assign a global to keep track of the lengths.

```
if (GLOBAL < len){
   GLOBAL = items.parent();
}
```

sets the global = the parent of the largest set of LI

Comment: I don't think this works as you think it does. `items.parent()` will simply return a jQuery collection containing each `<ul>`. In OP's sample markup, `GLOBAL` would be set to a collection containing all 3 `<ul>` elements.